# How can I get the smallest number, not in an array, in a functional programming fashion with lo-dash?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I have an array...

[8, 2, 5, 3, 0, 9, 1, 6, 7]

How do I get the smallest number, not listed in the array? `4` in this case.

The only thing I can think of is, but I would like to get rid of the while loop if I could.

```
var list = [8, 2, 5, 3, 9, 1, 6, 7];
var num = -1;
var done = false;
while (!done) {
  num++;
  if(!_.contains(list, num)) {
    done = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the lowest non negative number?  Or lowest number above the min?  What is the true requirement?

Comment: @ajon - The lowest non negative number.

Comment: What do you mean with 'get rid the while loop'? In any case you'll have to check all elements in one way or another. And by the way, in your example the lowest non negative number not in the array is 0

Comment: Pablo is right. The first array shown in the question has 0 in it but the array in the code snippet does not.

Comment: Is the question really about *any* array of integers *whatsoever*? Such array could contain thousands of elements, and repeated elements. Or are there constraints on how the array to be searched is constructed? I've often found that a theoretically "best" solution would not be the best solution in my specific situation because the theoretical solution was aiming for complete generality.

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the array in n lg n time and start at the beginning and find the first gap.

This solution solves for the lowest number between the min and max.  Otherwise, computationally, yours Is the best.

Comment: @pablo you are correct.  When I answered I didn't know if it was lowest non neg or min elt.

Comment: @ajon anyway my comment was incorrect. I could not edit so I deleted because could be misleading

Comment: This solution seems like an overkill.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the OP's solution the fastest. Using a loop to manually search whether a `list` contains `num` is much faster than using `!_.contains(list, num)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function findLowest(n, xs) {
    return xs.indexOf(n) < 0 ? n : findLowest(n + 1, xs);
}
```

Now all you need to do is:

```
var n = findLowest(0, [8, 2, 5, 3, 0, 9, 1, 6, 7]);

alert(n); // 4
```

See the demo for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/9pXGR/

The `findLowest` function will find the lowest number not in the list starting from a given number `n`.

Comment: This is a nice solution, sadly JS doesn't have TCO... You could write it in terms of `reduce` to not blow the stack with large arrays.

Comment: @elclanrs Isn't `reduce` also a recursive function? Wouldn't it also result in a StackOverflow? =P

Comment: Well, technically yes, in functional languages everything is implemented in terms of recursive reduction but in JavaScript it's implemented with iteration for obvious reasons, as `map`, `filter`,  `every`, etc...